# getServerSession always returning null in nextjs 13.5.2 api route handlers while using next auth for Oauth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

`I am currently working on a To-Do app to practice Next.js and Next-Auth. I am using Next-Auth for OAuth Provider and I want to add a 'createdBy' property to each to-do item with the corresponding user ID. This will allow me to fetch the to-do items for a specific user. However, I am facing issues in retrieving the details of the current user in API routes as the 'getServerSession' function is always returning null.

**Here is My Next auth setup**

```
import { authOptions } from '@/lib/auth-options'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'


const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export {handler as GET,handler as POST}
```

**Here are my authOptions**

```
import { type NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import { getAuthCredentials } from "./secrets";
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: getAuthCredentials().clientId,
      clientSecret: getAuthCredentials().clientSecret,
    }),
  ],
  secret: getAuthCredentials().secret,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: ({ token, user, session }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token?.id) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
    signOut: "/signout",
  },
};
```

In Server Components while using getServerSession(authOptions) is working fine
In Client Components while using useSession() is also working fine

but in api routes it is returning null

**Here is my api route handler for creating todo**
// api/todos

```
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  let body = await req.json();
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  console.log({ session });
  // {session : null}
  let validateBody = addTodoSchema.safeParse(body);
  console.log({ validateBody });
  if (!validateBody.success) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: false,
      error: validateBody.error,
    });
  }
  try {
    await connectToDatabase();
    let todo = await prisma.todo.create({
      data: {
        ...body,
        createdBy: session?.user.id,
      },
    });
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: true,
      data: todo,
      message: "Todo created successfully",
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log({ error });
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: false,
      error: error.message,
    });
  } finally {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  }
}
```

Here is the code to making request to the above endpoint

```
"use server";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
export const addTodo = async ({ title }: { title: string }) => {
  try {
    let res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/todos", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers(),
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
      }),
    });
    let data = await res.json();
    console.log({ data });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log({ error });
    // throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};
```

I am passing the title from the form when submit is clicked
and in the above code i added headers() i saw it somewhere but still it is not working

i am getting this error in terminal

**⨯ TypeError: Response body object should not be disturbed or locked**
**at extractBody**

can someone help me with this?

Thank You.
`your text`

`

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, I downgraded to 13.5.2 now its working fine for me.